# I want to remove the first part of this string however the number changes

Tags: python

I want to remove the first 3 numbers of any string that I put in the input.

```
response = input("Insert String: ")
```

If I were to put any string in the response it would print it with the first 3 characters removed.

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: number or character? What if the input is `'abc12d34e5'`?

Answer (score 4):

You can use string slicing.

```py
response=input("Insert string:")[3:]
```

For more information on how slicing works, check out [Understanding slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slicing) on Stack. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
response = input("Insert String: ")
prefixStr = response[:2]
last_3_chars = response[-3:]
print(last_3_chars, prefixStr, sep='\t')
```

Maybe? I'm not sure exactly what you mean. Please clarify your request.

Comment: The request is pretty clear tbh.

Comment: Just a note, this contains a mistake - `first_3_chars` will actually only be the first two chars.

Comment: @iteratedwalls apologies, you are correct. I will replace with `prefixStr`

Comment: Now `last_3_chars` is undefined, and it's still the first two characters. Also, why do you need the tab sep? Python will automatically separate arguments to `print` with spaces.

Comment: Firstly, do you mean `first_3_chars`? And secondly, I prefer `'\t'` especially in a debug environment. Just personal preference. But yes, I see what you mean. I just prefer it, it's generally just more comfortable and easier to see, especially with large projects.